# Is there a way to stop DOTA2 from working without reinstalling windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10, blocking, steam

I'm trying to find a way to block myself from being able to install dota on my PC, or to at least make it take a lot of effort to do so. I had been using cold turkey, but it was too easy to go around. The solution cannot block steam as a whole, as I do have some software I use connected to my account. Is there any register key i could edit or sth?

Comment: There is not a registry key that can block DOTA.

Comment: @Ramhound I expressed myself poorly- I'm aware you can't ban application in registry, I was rather asking if there is some non essential system component that i could break, which would only, or mostly, affect dota.

Answer (score 2):

You can try contacting steam support and asking them to restrict your account from playing the game for some time. I have heard some people doing it, not sure it works.

Answer (score 2):

As far as you've admin rights on your computer you can't effectively block yourself doing anything with it.

You may set up parental control to prevent playing DOTA then ask another person to change parental control AND admin password to something you don't know.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you are trying to block yourself or your kids from playing, but in any case Máté Juhász could be your answer.

However on a non technical level I would recommand you not to do this but rather allow yourself playing dota in your free time but in a controlled and non damaging manner. Cause playing pc games is OK!!! Playing too much while neglecting your RL is not.

If you want to play less, set yourself time limits like e.g. only play 2 hours after work or start at 8 and stop at 10 and then consciously make the decision yourself to stop playing. This will be much more successful approach. And it will be much more rewarding. Because if you break your block on a bad day, you will not reset the block. 
You basically will relaps harder.

Ask your squad to please not push you to play and if you want to stop, don´t nag you to continue as you want to get your shit together they should understand if not, change your friends.
Set yourself set time intervals or time limits in which you are allowed to play
Give yourself incentives to really stop playing
E.g.

- do sport always after your game session
- Cook dinner
- Watch television with your wifu
- clean your appartement
- Read/listen to a book

If you want this for your kid, note that there is always a way around these things no matter what you do. And with enough time on their hands because they cannot play dota these little trolls will find a way to break your lock. Total prohibition would also be a wrong approach from an education/parenting point of view. And would rather be counter productive to what you want to achieve.

On a technical level, try this
[Edit registry](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/8739/restrict-users-to-run-only-specified-programs-in-windows-7/)

Answer (score 0):

> Use Steam Family View - With Family View you can restrict content,
>   pretty much like a parental lock (which is kind of what it is). The
>   only drawback here is that you know the PIN code so could easily
>   bypass it, and if you forgot the PIN code you'll need to contact Steam
>   Support to access restricted material! For details on Family View see
>   here:
>   https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=5149-EOPC-9918

Would recomend this solution, and let a friend choose the pin code

GL&BR

Comment: Thinking about this solution, i already thought of an bypass...
Make a new Acc - dota is free2play...